# Windows 8.1 desktop connected to network but cannot access Internet or NAS

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a self-built desktop that is running windows 8.1 and was working flawlessly for the past two years, however recently it has developed a problem where it is not able to access the internet or the NAS on the network that it is connected to.

The computer is connected to the network with Wi-Fi from an add-on card and is able to connect without issues however the computer is unable to access anything on the network or the internet. Other computers on the same network are having no problems. I have tried to fix this problem extensively before making an account here to ask as a last resort. I have listed how I have tried to fix this problem below.

- Restarting the computer and all network equipment
- Updating drivers
- Trying three other Wi-Fi cards that are known to work
- Checking that the adapter is assigned an IP address
- Anti-Virus Scans
- Running Windows in safe mode
- Reinstalling Windows

After some of these fixes where attempted the computer was able to regain connection to the internet for a few seconds to a minute however the problems quickly restarted.

The motherboard being used is an AsRock z77 Pro 4.

Update:
I have plugged the computer into the modem directly with ethernet and it is working without any problems and can acess the internet just fine. I am using the computer to type this update.

Thanks

Comment: Does it work with a wired connection?

Comment: I will try pluging it into a wired connection when I get home this evening.

Comment: I have tested connecting it with ethernet and it works.

Comment: Is your wifi working?

Comment: The wifi says that it is connected but it is acting as if it is not.

Comment: Can you run IP Config when you are connected to the WIFI only and provide the output? (Windows Key + R, type CMD in the "Run" diaglog that pops up, to start the command prompt, then type "ipconfig /all" and enter) Also, do you have "wireless isolation" or any kind of Access Control enabled on your router? You may have accidently blacklisted your own WIFI card's MAC address?